# Android : Get the screen rotation from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, screen-orientation, android-broadcast

I have a **AlarmManager** that execute an **Intent Broadcast** every 5min :

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 300000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, Sensors.class), 0));
```

Inside the **BroadcastReceiver's onReceive** method, I need to know the device orientation (0°, 90°, 180°, 270°) :

```
int orientation = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
```

Everything works fine. But when I minimize or close the app, the screen's rotation always returns 0° (orientation of android home screen), even if the device is lying horizontally.

How can I know the device's rotation from a BroadcastReceiver, independently of the app or device's status?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally used the accelerometer to solve this problem :

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) != null) {
final SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

        int orientation;

        // Vertical
        if (Math.abs(event.values[1]) > Math.abs(event.values[0]) && Math.abs(event.values[1]) > Math.abs(event.values[2]))
            if (event.values[1] > 0)
                orientation = 0; // Head Up
            else
                orientation = 180; // Head Down

        // Horizontal
        else if (Math.abs(event.values[0]) > Math.abs(event.values[1]) && Math.abs(event.values[0]) > Math.abs(event.values[2]))
            if (event.values[0] > 0)
                orientation = 90; // Left
            else
                orientation = 270; // Right

        // Flat
        else
            orientation = 0;
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
};

sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](http://www.41post.com/4696/programming/android-obtaining-the-current-orientation-using-a-broadcastreceiver) may be useful for future searchers.

the first thing that’s going to be required to make this work is to create a class that inherits from `BroadcastReceiver` and implements the `onReceive()` method. This method tells what the `BroadcastReceiver` should do when the correct Intent is detected. So, for now, a child of the `BroadcastReceiver` class is being defined so as the code that has to execute when the `BroadcastReceiver` is triggered. Later on this tutorial, you will find how to filter intents to detect orientation changes. For the sake of simplicity, the code below detects orientation changes and the angle of the device, displaying this info in Toast notifications. Here’s the code:

```
package fortyonepost.com.orientationbrec;   

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.content.res.Configuration;  
import android.view.Surface;  
import android.view.WindowManager;  
import android.widget.Toast;  

public class OrientationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  
{  
    //An integer that holds the value of the orientation given by the current configuration  
    private int configOrientation;  

    //A WindowManager object that will act as a handle to the window service  
    private WindowManager wm;  
    //An integer that holds the value of the orientation (in degrees) given by the window service  
    private int windowServOrientation;  

    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  
    {  
        //Get the orientation from the current configuration object  
        configOrientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;  

        //Display the current orientation using a Toast notification  
        switch (configOrientation)  
        {  
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:  
            {  
                Toast.makeText(context, "Orientation is LANDSCAPE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                break;  
            }  
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:  
            {  
                Toast.makeText(context, "Orientation is PORTRAIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                break;  
            }  
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE:  
            {  
                Toast.makeText(context, "Orientation is SQUARE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                break;  
            }  

            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:  
            default:  
            {  
                Toast.makeText(context, "Orientation is UNDEFINED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                break;  
            }  
        }   

        //Get a handle to the Window Service  
        wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);  
        //Query the current orientation made available by the Window Service  
        //The getOrientation() method is deprecated. Instead, use getRotation() when targeting Android API 8 (Android 2.2 - Froyo) or above.  
        windowServOrientation =  wm.getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();  

        //Display the current orientation using a Toast notification  
        switch (windowServOrientation)  
        {  
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:  
            {  
                Toast.makeText(context, "Rotation is 0 degrees.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                break;  
            }  

            case Surface.ROTATION_90:  
            {  
                Toast.makeText(context, "Rotation is 90 degrees.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                break;  
            }  

            case Surface.ROTATION_180:  
            {  
                Toast.makeText(context, "Rotation is 180 degrees.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                break;  
            }  

            case Surface.ROTATION_270:  
            {  
                Toast.makeText(context, "Rotation is 270 degrees.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                break;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Here’s the Activity that is responsible for registering and `unregistering` the `BroadcastReceiver`. Here’s the code:

```
package fortyonepost.com.orientationbrec;  

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.content.IntentFilter;  
import android.os.Bundle;  

public class OrientationBroadcastReceiverActivity extends Activity  
{  
    //Create and initialize an OrientationBroadcastReceiver object  
    private OrientationBroadcastReceiver orientationBR = new OrientationBroadcastReceiver();  
    //Create and initialize a new IntentFilter  
    private IntentFilter orientationIF = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED);  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
    {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onResume()  
    {  
        //Register the Orientation BroadcasReceiver  
        this.registerReceiver(orientationBR, orientationIF);  
        super.onResume();  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onPause()  
    {  
        //Unregister the Orientation BroadcasReceiver to avoid a BroadcastReceiver leak  
        this.unregisterReceiver(orientationBR);  
        super.onPause();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation) is what you are searching for.

```
context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

You can get real time changes [this way](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)).

Comment: Thank You @M66B, but it returns "landscape" or "portrait". I need to know the rotation (0°, 90°, 180° or 270°)